# How to install React-bootstrap and markdown with Yarn?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, yarn-lock.json, javascript-marked

I created the app wiyh **npx-create-app**, yarn start workes well. But when I try to install **React-bootstrap** and **marked** with **Yarn**:

```
yarn add react-bootstrap bootstrap
yarn add marked
```

The modules doesn't appeared in the package.json file. Doesn't worked.
This is the console:
[image]

Then I tried with npm :

```
npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap 
npm install marked
```

That's worked well.

Why that's doesn't work with yarn ?
I tried also to make **yarn install** before but the console displayed "info No lockfile found". So I'm litle confused with yarn. What I have to do, in which order ?

Comment: I wonder why nobody answer me...

Comment: nobody can help ?